# Prove that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all integers

Tags: number-theory

**This result has been disproven.**

> Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be an arithmetic progression and suppose that $$x_1^3, \quad x_1^3 + x_2^3, \quad x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3, \quad x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3+x_4^4$$ are perfect squares. Prove that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are all integers.

Since these numbers are in arithmetic progression, we must have $x_1,x_1+d,x_1+2d,x_1+3d$ are our four terms. Also, $x_1$ must either be a perfect square, or the cubic root of a perfect square and $x_2,x_3$ must be integers or cubic roots. I thought about proving the latter is impossible by showing that the distance between the cubic roots of integers is unique ($\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]b)$, so that $x_4^3$ can't be an integer. How do we continue from here?

Comment: We only have to show that $x_1$ is an integer, because then $x_2=x_1+d$ and $x_3=x_1+2d$ are integers as well, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde We could have $x_1 = 1,x_2 = 1+(\sqrt[3]{3}-1)$.

Comment: Ah, so $d$ need not be an integer, as it is often the definition for arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @dietrich.  You also have to show $d$ is an integer.

Comment: Not fair to change the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not true.  Let $x_1 = t^{2/3}$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = -t^{2/3}$ for any positive integer $t$ that is not a cube.

EDIT: For the new question, it's still not true (assuming there are nontrivial integer solutions).  Given any integer solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, not all $0$, multiply all of these by $2^{2/3}$ and you get a non-integer solution.

Comment: Um $x_3^3 = -t^2$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: $x_1^3 = t^2$, $x_1^3 + x_2^3 = t^2$, $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 = 0$ are all squares.

Comment: Oops  You are right.

Comment: I changed the question to four terms.

Comment: Well, the new question may be true if the only integer solution is $(0,0,0,0)$.  @user19405892, Robert gives you a counterexample, provided that there exists a nonzero integral solution $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a counter example for every $n$ and for every $t$ which is not a third power of a integer.
$$x_n=n\cdot t^{2/3}\\x_1^3+x_2^3+\cdots+x_n^3=t^2(n^3+(n-1)^3+\cdots+1^3)=t^2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$
For example take $x_1=2^{2/3},x_2=2\cdot2^{2/3},x_3=3\cdot 2^{2/3},x_4=4\cdot 2^{2/3} $